# Facebook app requried ssl

Tags: facebook, ssl, web-hosting

i've recently wrote an app for facebook.

the app is currently sitting on a free-webhost (000webhost).

I've tried to publish my app but since I have a non secured URL it didnt work.

I've also checked my free webhoster and unfortounatly it doesent support ssl certification.

doese anyone know a way to bypass the need for an ssl certification for facebook apps?

or anyone know of a free webhoster that support ssl certifications?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Google Apps supports SSL for free, but it may not be applicable for your use-case
Also, heroku supports SSL on free accounts, which seems to be a popular choice